Is it possible to add a link of social media to my Google Business Profile locations?
I want to know if it's possible to link URLs from various social media platforms, such as Facebook and Instagram, to a location in the Google Business Profile (GBP). Is there a specific API for this action? If so, I would appreciate any tips or links to documentation.
I am searching to do something like:
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import authorizations.Authorize;
import java.util.List;
private static void SocialMedia() throws Exception {
            List<String>  locationNamesList =  ReadAllLocationsInfo() ;
            Credential authorization = Authorize.getAuthorization();
            String access_token = authorization.getAccessToken();
            for(String locationName:locationNamesList) {
                // for example assigning the related facebook page to this accounts/accound_id/locations/location_id 
            }
        }


The FAQ here for 'Is it possible to update social media links in bulk?' suggests using the API to manage social media links for multiple locations. But I can't find any such documented API. It may be planned considering this is a (relatively) new feature for Google Business Profiles. https://support.google.com/business/answer/13580646?hl=en#zippy=%2Cis-it-possible-to-update-social-media-links-in-bulk
